# Why does my "goto" loop?

Tags: c++

When I run this program, my output is just a loop of my cout. it as if the cin is now getting skipped? Does anybody have an idea as to why this is happening?

```
TryAgain:
 cout<<"\nEnter a number greater than 1 and less than 100: ";                // 21 - Request a Number
 cin>>num;                                                                   // 22 - Store the number

      if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Please enter a number!\n\n";
        goto TryAgain;
         }

      if (num<=1){                                                           // 24 - IF NUMBER IS BELOW 1
          cout<<"Oh no, " << num << " is too small!\n\n";                    // 25 - Print Error Message
            return 0;
           }

      if (num>=100){                                                         // 29 - IF NUMBER IS OVER 100
          cout<<"Oh no, " << num << " is too large!\n\n";                    // 30 - Print Error Message
            return 0;
           }


          else  if (isprime(num)){  //Call isprime                           // 34 - IF ISPRIME IS TRUE
          cout << "True, " << num << " is a prime number!!\n\n";             // 35 - Print True Message
          }

                   else{                                                     // 38 - IF ISPRIME OS FALSE
                   cout << "False, " << num << " is not a prime number!!\n\n"; // 39 - rint False Message
                   }
```

Comment: Why not just use a loop construct instead of `goto`?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step.

Comment: You should really take a look at what Dijkstra (inventor of the algorithm that makes the internet packet delivery quick) has to say about [goto](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)

Comment: `inventor of the algorithm that makes the internet work fast` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @dolan I just assumed he wouldn't know who he is so I made it plain and simple lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `cin` fails, it is put into an error state that will cause it to always fail. You need to clear that error state.

```
cin.clear();
```

If you're going to do the same input operation again, you also need to remove (at least some of) the previously entered data, or else `cin` will fail again.

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Just want to note that you got to `#include <limits>` for `numeric_limits`.

Comment: What is all of the extra information inside of the parentheses? I noticed that the program works JUST by using "cin.ignore()"

Comment: @Tanner: Try entering a non-numeric string greater than 1 character.  The thing inside the parenthesis (`numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`) is just a really really large number, which is the maximum number `ignore` can take as a parameter.

Comment: @Tanner: Essentially, I'm asking `cin` to ignore up until it finds a newline character, or up to a certain number of characters (which is the max amount of characters I am allowed to specify), whichever comes first.

Comment: And I noticed the program works fine without including <limits>

Comment: @Tanner: Only by coincidence, because one of the other headers in your standard library implementation happens to bring it in. You cannot rely on that behavior if you want your code to be portable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two member functions of std::cin: ignore and clear. For example

```
#include <limits>

//...
  if (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Please enter a number!\n\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );
    goto TryAgain;
     }
```

Also it is a bad idea to use goto statement.  You could write

```
do
{
    if ( !cin ) 
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );
    }

    cout<<"\nEnter a number greater than 1 and less than 100: ";
    cin>>num;
} while ( !cin );
```

Comment: You need to put the call to `ignore` after the call to `clear`. `ignore` is an input operation too, and will fail if the `istream` is in an error state.